# How to read currency values in Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers

I have currency values in the following format in a CSV file.

```
$171.5M
$2.74B
```

How do I have Numbers recognize these as proper currency values for sorting?

Comment: Do we presume you’re on macOS version of pages? (Or perhaps iOS or iPad or web?)

Comment: Yes, this is for Numbers on macOS.

Comment: What you need to do is multiply the M number by 1.0x10^6 and the B number by 1.0x10^9. This will give you the values with all the digits. i have tried to get Numbers to recognize that format with no luck...

Comment: I’ll play with the new REGEX formulas in the new version of Numbers and see what can be done but that may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the letters  B or M in the cell. you have to use all the digits.  Open numbers and on the right side of the window, on the top right corner be sure to click on Format. You should have 4 tabs underneath Format that read "Table, Cell, Text, Arrange. Click on the Cell tab and a new panel appears with a pulldown menu Data Format. One of the options under this menu is Currency, select that and you should be good to go.  My setting is Automatic and it usually recognizes the $ sign as currency.  See image below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does that sort Millions vs Billions as the op shows in the question?

Comment: This answer does not appear to work with the same data provided in the OP. Please use the sample data in the OP, not just something arbitrary you've typed in.

Comment: you can't put the M and B after the numbers.  That doesn't work, you have to put all the digits in.

Comment: it doesn't matter which digits i use as long as i put them all in.

Comment: @bjbk  - Sorry but you can't use the B and M digits after the numbers. you need to put in all the digits.

Comment: That’s what I thought, but find the have time to verify.

Comment: I'm not an accountant but I've never seen that representation of number before.

Comment: This is data I'm importing. These values represent the market cap values of companies. I'm wondering if there is a quick way for Numbers to interpret these values and convert them to numbers so I can sort this column correctly.